# Is there a way to fast forward using audioPlayers FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, audio-player

I was wondering if audiopayers package has 30Sec fast forward.

I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) flutter package to play audio but I did not find any fast forward
so can u guide me where is the fast forward?
Thanks for guiding me :)

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in the document there is a function call seek() that let u fast forward.
Try calling this:

```
await audioPlayer.pause();
await audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: 30));
await audioPlayer.resume();
```

Comment: Thanks a million. u know I was in a hurry because the deadline of my project arrived and I had some bugs so I didn't read the documentation carefully. thanks

Comment: And one more thing, how can we speed up the audio?

Comment: i have used seek and its not working when i set to seek for 30 seconds it again start